# I am trying to insert custom tab into Activity tab but it is not working

Tags: api, hooks, civix

I am creating new extension.
I am adding a new custom field into Activity tab but it's not working

### //Creating a custom group for survey

```
function custom_group_create_survey(){
$survey_custom_group = array(
    "id" => "10",
    "name" => "API_survey",
    "title" => "API survey",
    "extends" => "Activity",
    "extends_entity_column_value" => [
        "1"
    ],
    "style" => "Inline",
    "collapse_display" => "1",
    "weight" => "   3",
    "is_active" => "1",
    "table_name" => "civicrm_value_API_sur__5",
    "is_multiple" => "0",
    "collapse_adv_display" => "0",
    "created_id" => "2",
    "created_date" => "",
    "is_reserved" => "0",
    "is_public" => "1"
);

try{
    $result = civicrm_api3('CustomGroup', 'create', $survey_custom_group);
}
catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
    // Handle error here.
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
    $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
    return array(
        'is_error' => 1,
        'error_message' => $errorMessage,
        'error_code' => $errorCode,
        'error_data' => $errorData,
    );
}

return $result;
```

}

```
function custom_field_create_survey() {
$params = array(
    'custom_group_id' => 10,
    'name' => 'test_textfield2',
    'label' => 'Name1',
    'html_type' => 'Text',
    'data_type' => 'String',
    'default_value' => 'abc',
    'weight' => 4,
    'is_required' => 1,
    'is_searchable' => 0,
    'is_active' => 1,
);

try{
    $result = civicrm_api3('CustomField', 'create', $params);
}
catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
    // Handle error here.
    $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
    $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
    $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
    return array(
        'is_error' => 1,
        'error_message' => $errorMessage,
        'error_code' => $errorCode,
        'error_data' => $errorData,
    );
}

return $result;
```

} ##

I am calling these functions into following hook

```
function surveytab_civicrm_install() {
custom_group_create_survey();
custom_field_create_survey();
```

_surveytab_civix_civicrm_install();
}
 ##

[image: This is created by using custom field (administer)]

Comment: Are you getting any error in your CiviCRM log or general error log?

Comment: No any error. I checked in API explorer.

Comment: What is the message of the Exception? Or is there no exception?

Answer (score 1):

I have an example of how I deal with creating custom groups and fields in an extension here: https://lab.civicrm.org/partners/civicoop/dmgeneriek/tree/master/CRM/Dmgeneriek/ConfigItems

- The definition of the custom groups and fields are in the resources folder in json files
- The ConfigItems class is initiated in the Upgrader (see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-upgrader)

I recommend avoiding using hard coded custom group id's in your code.